# Total Function Over Two Different Sets Where A is a subset of B

Tags: functions

Let A be the set of all integers between 1 and 100. Let B be all integers. If I have a function f: A -> B, such that f(x) = x+1, the images are basically the set of integers between 11 and 101. Since there are many integers in B that has no input in A, can we say f is a total function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes, $f$ is a total function as every element of $A$ has an image in $B$.
- For the concern that you raise, if there is any element in $B$ that has no preimage in $A$, we say that the function $f$ is not a [surjective function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function).